# Swift file with class to Android studio

Tags: java, android, swift

I've being reading about `Swift` future in Android development and come across [this](http://romain.goyet.com/articles/running_swift_code_on_android/) article about running swift code on android. And now I am curious if I can somehow port my whole data model classes with `init(data: JSON)` into studio, in order to save time of android developers rewriting them to Java. Or it is too early to consider options like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [this](https://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/silver/).

> Built on over ten years of solid compiler knowledge and technology, Silver is a truly native Swift compiler for the .NET CLR, the Java/Android JVM, the Cocoa runtime and our new native Island platform.

Basically Remobjects built a compiler for swift that can compile swift into native Java/Android code.